# Woocommerce: conditionally display products in shop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When my customers visit the shop, I want to only display products when they have added certain information to their profile.

How can I conditionally display products?

Comment: What do you mean by "certain information to their profile"?

Comment: Basically, the user adds information to their profile. And that information determines whether the product is visible or not. However, the question asks "How can I conditionally display products?". I'm looking for guidance on a hook for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using the `pre_get_posts` hook, as the WooCommerce shop page uses a global WP_Query.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

You can make your function specifically targeted to this page using `is_shop()` https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/